# CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR after upgarde to tensorflow-gpu 1.9

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and am using python 2.7 and tensorflow-gpu 1.6 which works fine.

After upgrading to tensorflow-gpu 1.9 with `pip` I get the following error message:

`could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR`

I have CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.0.5.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution given in [RuntimeError: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810356/runtimeerror-cudnn-status-internal-error) also worked for me. In short, run

`sudo rm -rf ~/.nv`

and reboot.